# Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm getting the above error message, could you find out why?

```
$mysqli=new mysqli("localhost", "***", "***","***") or die($mysqli->connect_error);
        
function checklogin($username, $password){
    global $mysqli;
        
    $result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");
    $result->bind_param("s", $username);
    $result->execute();
  
    if($result != false){
        $dbArray=$result->fetch_array();
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure PHP is compiled with mysqli built-in (e.g. --with-mysqli).  Alternatively, if it's compiled separately as an extension, you need to make sure you're loading it in the appropriate php.ini file (you can check via phpinfo()).

Also, I presume you're using:

```
global $mysqli;
```

for the sake of example, but for anyone else stumbling across this, that's potentially a horrible idea.